# I can't open dcm file

Tags: python, pydicom

Please tell me, when I try to open a dcm file, an error occurs, I use the pydicom library, how can I fix it?

```
base = r"D:\fff"
pass_dicom = "dd.dcm" 
  
# enter DICOM image name for pattern 
# result is a list of 1 element 
filename = pydicom.data.data_manager.get_files(base, pass_dicom)
  
ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
```

Gives this error: No tag to read at file position 3AC03D2

I found a piece of code that throws an error, it throws an error if bytes_read = b''

```
def read_sequence_item(
    fp: BinaryIO,
    is_implicit_VR: bool,
    is_little_endian: bool,
    encoding: Union[str, MutableSequence[str]],
    offset: int = 0
) -> Optional[Dataset]:
    """Read and return a single :class:`~pydicom.sequence.Sequence` item, i.e.
    a :class:`~pydicom.dataset.Dataset`.
    """
    seq_item_tell = fp.tell() + offset
    if is_little_endian:
        tag_length_format = "<HHL"
    else:
        tag_length_format = ">HHL"
    try:
        bytes_read = fp.read(8)
        group, element, length = unpack(tag_length_format, bytes_read)
    except BaseException:
        raise IOError(
            f"No tag to read at file position {fp.tell() + offset:X}"
        )
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: As you write in the comment, you get a list from `get_files`, not a string, so this certainly can't work.

Comment: I tried to write directly: im = pydicom.dcmread(dd.dcm'), but still the same error

Comment: I also found dcm files on the Internet and they worked for me, but it’s my dcm files that don’t work, I think maybe it can be fixed somehow using specific_tags, but I don’t know how

Comment: Ok, in this case you may provide an anonymized version of the DICOM file in question, or at at least the output of dcmdump or such. Also try to open the file with another application. Maybe you just got an invalid DICOM file, but without further information there is no way to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Again, the symptoms seem to indicate that the input file is corrupted. We can't reproduce without access to (probably a scaled-down version of) the file.